# Prove that the circles has at least a common point of intersection

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

In the interior of a unit square, there are $n(n\in \mathbb{N}^*)$ circles whose sum of areas is greater than $n-1$. Prove that the circles has at least a common point of intersection

I really don't know where to start. Thanks

Comment: What about the obvious solutions with $n=1$ or with concentric circles as long as $n\le 4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** after reinterpretation of the problem statement.

If all circles contain the center of the square, we are done.
If a circle does not contain the center, then its diameter is $<\frac{\sqrt 2}2$ and its area is $<\frac\pi8$. 
For all other circles, we have that the diameter is $\le 1$ and area $\le\frac \pi 4$. Thus the total area $A$ of the circles is 
$$n-1<A\le (n-1)\frac\pi 4+\frac\pi 8.$$
By solving for $n-1$, we find
$$(n-1)<\frac{\frac\pi 8}{1-\frac\pi4}=1.829\ldots,$$
i.e. $n\le 2$.
The case $n=1$ is trivial.
If $n=2$, the total area of the disks is $>1$ hence greater than the area of the unit square, hence they must intersect.

Comment: I think the question was to prove that there exists a point in the unit square which is contained in *all* the circles

Comment: @VincentNivoliers But that variant is also quite trivial as soon as $n-1\ge1$. Oh, wait - maybe it's not.

Comment: What I find trivial is to prove that any two circles intersect, however proving that one point is contained in every circle seems less trivial. I may be mistaken.

Comment: I was writing the same proof, you're faster !